# iOS 10 Safari browser injects links for phone numbers

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

I have a div which is hidden. The div contains json data which is read and parsed by react components. The problem is on iOS, safari keeps changing the values of the phone numbers like this.

Original:

```
<div id='data' style='display: none'>{"phone":"012345678"}</div>
```

Safari:

```
<div id='data' style='display: none'>{"phone":"<a href="tel: 012345678">012345678</a>"}</div>
```

This causes JSON.parse() failing on client side. How can I stop this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion from Maimilano Poggio is very good. However it didn't work for me since I still want auto-formatting for phone numbers work in other parts of the webpage. Hence, I came up with my own solution. Instead of using `<div/>` tag, I use `<pre/>` tag. This makes sure the relevant parts don't get formatted by accidents in iOS safari.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add this to your html index

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```